# Polymorphism alternatives in rust

Tags: rust, struct

I have 2 very similar structs and I wanted to ask if there is something similar like polymorphism in java/kotlin in rust?

```
struct Player {
    jump_power: f32,
    color: Color,

    size: (f32, f32),
    pos: (f32, f32),
}

struct Pipe {
    color: Color,
    speed: f32,

    size: (f32, f32),
    pos: (f32, f32),
}
```

I'm not sure where exactly I should start.

Comment: There is no struct inheritance in rust. You could try *composition* (extract the same values into another struct and put a field of this new type into your other structs).

Comment: Start with identifying the exact problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: Unless this is a simplified version of a much larger problem, I wouldn’t worry about trying to save a couple of lines. It’s better to have a tiny amount of duplication if it avoids indirection.

Answer (score 2):

Rust often requires a different approach to fit more neatly into what Rust has in the way of capabilities. If you want something that can be either a `Pipe` or a `Player` then you probably want an `enum`:

```rust
enum Actor {
  Player(Player),
  Pipe(Pipe)
}
```

Where now that `Actor` can be one of either of those things.

Where you have common properties like `color` you can even do:

```rust
impl Actor {
    pub fn color(&self) -> Color {
        match self {
            Self::Player(p) => p.color,
            Self::Pipe(p) => p.color
        }
    }
}
```

Often you'll want to `impl From<Player> for Actor` as a convenience when constructing these, but that's not the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with traits and generics:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Color {
    rgb: [u8; 3],
}

trait ColorType {
    fn color(&self) -> &Color;
}

struct Player {
    jump_power: f32,
    color: Color,

    size: (f32, f32),
    pos: (f32, f32),
}

impl ColorType for Player {
    fn color(&self) -> &Color {
        &self.color
    } 
}

struct Pipe {
    color: Color,
    speed: f32,

    size: (f32, f32),
    pos: (f32, f32),
}

impl ColorType for Pipe {
    fn color(&self) -> &Color {
        &self.color
    }
}

fn get_color<T: ColorType>(my_color_type: &T) -> &Color {
    &my_color_type.color()
}

fn main() {
    let pipe = Pipe {
        color: Color { rgb: [255u8, 255u8, 255u8] },
        speed: 0.0,
        size: (0.0, 0.0),
        pos: (0.0, 0.0),
    };
    
    let player = Player {
        jump_power: 0.0,
        color: Color { rgb: [255u8, 255u8, 255u8] },
        size: (0.0, 0.0),
        pos: (0.0, 0.0),
    };
    
    println!("Pipe color: {:#?}", get_color(&pipe));
    println!("Player color: {:#?}", get_color(&player));
}
```

output:

```
Pipe color: Color {
    rgb: [
        255,
        255,
        255,
    ],
}
Player color: Color {
    rgb: [
        255,
        255,
        255,
    ],
}
```

[Rust Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=58d001d83e03cc8a16dfedca1c9461ab)